# how to avoid Illegal key size warning in hierynomus ssh

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, ssh-keys, sshj

i have disable the host key checking ssh but it logs **illegal key size warning**

```
SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
    ssh.addHostKeyVerifier(new HostKeyVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String arg0, int arg1, PublicKey arg2) {

      return true;
    }});

    ssh.connect(hostIP, CommonProperties.SSH_PORT);
    ssh.authPassword(serverUserName, serverPassword);
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'Illegal Key Size' warnings typically are displayed when either:

1. You are not running with the *Unlimited Strength* Java Cryptography Extensions
2. BouncyCastle could not be loaded.

These are just warnings that SSHJ will only use limited strength cryptography, which is of course less secure.